# Can I develop for ServiceStack.Authentication.OpenId on localhost without requiring certs and hosts file changes?

Tags: c#, servicestack, openid

I'm working on implementing OpenID based single sign-on using ServiceStack.Authentication.OpenId. and have run into an annoyance that I want to solve. For development I would like to be able to test on my local machine without having to self-sign a certificate and change my hosts file. This way I can easily distribute the code to our other developers without needing to include a set of instructions for how to get it working on a local machine.

We are using DotNetOpenAuth as the provider, which actually allows this by itself by configuring it with:

```
<dotNetOpenAuth>

<relyingParty>
    <security requireSsl="false" />
    <behaviors>
      <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                             with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
      <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth" />
    </behaviors>
  </relyingParty>
</openid>
<messaging>
  <untrustedWebRequest>
    <whitelistHosts>
      <!-- since this is a sample, and will often be used with localhost -->
      <add name="localhost" />
    </whitelistHosts>
  </untrustedWebRequest>
</messaging>
```

However I have not yet found a way to utilize a similar setup through ServiceStack. Is anyone able to shed insight on how to set this up? The error I currently get when attempting to use it in this manner is as follows:

```
The URL 'http://localhost:8080/OpenId' is rated unsafe and cannot be requested this way.
```